# Textbox doesn't clear

Tags: c#, asp.net

I fill my texboxes with:

```
foreach (User u in userInfo)
{
    txtNickname.Text = u.Nickname;
    txtFirstName.Text = u.FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = u.LastName;
    txtEmail.Text = u.Email;
}
```

My textboxes are now filled with the data from the database.

For example I fill new values in all of the texboxes and I click on the button, than happens this:

```
if (txtNickname.Text != String.Empty && txtFirstName.Text != String.Empty && txtLastName.Text != String.Empty && txtEmail.Text != String.Empty)
{
   //TODO
}
```

But when I debug: the values of the textboxes are the old values (the values from the foreach-loop), and not the new values which I fill in the textboxes.

Why is this happening? I'm loading some data from the database in the textboxes, after that I'm changing the values of the textboxes myself, and when I debug the textbox values are still the database-values (see foreach-loop).

Comment: Is the first loop called in the Page_Load event? Did you check for Page.IsPostback?

Comment: What Steve suggests.  If you're overwriting the values on every Page_Load, you'll need to restrict it to pulling from the database only when it's not a postback (ie `if (!IsPostBack) { /* populate from db */ }`).  Otherwise you're just overwriting what the user submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first loop is executed in the Page_Load event then you should be sure that you don't execute again when the page is posted back as result of clicking on the button.

More info in [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) on MSDN

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // This code should be executed only when the page is being 
        // rendered for the first time not when is responding to a postback 
        // raised by the <runat="server">  controls
        UserInfoCollection userInfo = GetUserInfoCollection();

        foreach (User u in userInfo)
        {
            txtNickname.Text = u.Nickname;
            txtFirstName.Text = u.FirstName;
            txtLastName.Text = u.LastName;
            txtEmail.Text = u.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the problem, however it would be nice to know why there's a `foreach`.

Comment: @Matthew agree, it doesn't make sense. Only if I suppose that there is some support method that returns a collection but the collection contains just one user....

Comment: Yes it was in the Page_Load. This works! Thank you so much. The reason that I am using a foreach is that I am reading the user info from the database (based on session) and put that in a List.

Comment: All right then but you know that, if you have more than one user, the loop above will show only the info of the last user in the List. If you want to see all the users then you need a gridview or similar controls